# Bitwise "& " on a long?

Tags: java, android

I want to obtain the least 32 bits from a number of type long, so I perform bitwise operation "&" on the number with bits mask 0xFFFFFFFF, but the result is not correct, it still contains the other bits.

for example:

```
long a = 0x1234567890ab; 
long b = (a & 0xffffffff);
```

I expect the value of b to be 0x567890ab

but in practice, it is still 0x1234567890ab

Comment: As a C programer (25+ years) I am used to use unsigned variables to avoid sign extension issues but in this case I should have tought to add the L at the end of my litteral. I am learning java and I will probably fall into some other pitfalls :o)

Comment: Damn good question.  I just came across this and the answer was quite a surprise.  Is this one missing from Java Puzzlers? :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try this:

```
long a = 0x1234567890ab;  
long b = (a & 0xffffffffL);
```

`0xffffffff` is a literal of type `int`, for performing `&` with `long` it's promoted to type `long` by [sign extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension), therefore it turns into `0xffffffffffffffff`. To avoid sign extension you need to write it as a literal of type `long`: `0xffffffffL`.

Comment: I figured it out just after posting the question :o) Thanks anyway.

Comment: This answer, and the original question, saved me from spending a long time fiddling with the Eclipse Debugger! Thanks for the explanation and the link about _sign-extension_.

Comment: Thank you, you just saved me an awful lot of time!

Answer (score 3):

Does using 0xffffffffL make any difference?

I think what happens is that 0xffffffff gets upcasted to a long, and since both int and long are signed it tries to keep the same sign.

So, since 0xffffffff is -1 as an int, it gets converted to -1 as a long, or 0xffffffffffffffff

Answer (score -1):

try doing a bitwise AND with a long value with some leading zeroes instead of a 32 bit value. right now you're basically doing nothing to the number.